# Tag suggestion for exception or error

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we have separate tag for [exception](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exception) or [error](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) which could indicate the posts dealing with the errors? Which can ask how to deal with or debug specific exceptions/errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual guidelines about tags suggest to use tags that:

- don't say anything about the user who is asking the question
- describe a specific area of expertise

For example, [beginner](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) is a tag that describes the user who asks the question, not the question itself. [error](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) doesn't describe a specific area of Drupal expertise. Differently, [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views) describes a specific area of expertise, in the same way [cck](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cck) does.

Keep in mind that not everything in a question needs to be captured with a tag; tags are for the most important parts of the question. Considering there is a limit of 5 tags per question, we need to limit the tags to those that are really helpful, which don't apply to 50/60% of the questions (or more), but not even to very few questions.

Answer (score 1):

Issues found in existing modules are defined as off-topic. If all you have is an exception or error message, you shouldn't posting here. Module's issue queue is right place for such posts.

Tags for off-topic questions serves no real purpose, so should not be created.